# Remove All Characters Trailing an Angle Bracket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to clean up email strings surrounded by extra characters. The method I am using is as follows:

```
def email_clean(email)
    email = email.gsub(/(<+\w)/, "")
    email = email.gsub(/(>+\w)/, "")
    email = email.gsub(/(\w+=)/,"")  
    email = email.gsub(/(\w+:)/, "")
    email = email.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
    email = email.delete('"')
    return email
end
```

I'm calling it with the following example string:

```
email_clean("href="mailto:darren@*********.com"><span")
```

And getting the following output:

```
darren@*********.coman
```

I am trying to figure out why the first two gsub calls did not remove the trailing "an" when removing the angle brackets.

Comment: Are all your strings of format : `"href="mailto:email"><span"`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 At the moment, but not necessarily in future test cases. Ideally, I'd like to create a method that handles a broad range of emails that need to be cleaned.

Comment: Why don't you just extract the `mailto:[email address]` part instead of whittling away surrounding characters?

Comment: You could extract the email with something like `/[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+/i` which is taken from [the rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#table-valid_email_regex)

Comment: @sagarpandya82 That regular expression is wrong and will skip a lot of valid emails like `test+addr@gmail.com` and other crazy stuff that's becoming more common-place with top-level domains being used by organizations. `google.` is a domain, so `x@google` is theoretically a valid email address. There's also iTLDs like `삼성.` (Samsung) which are valid as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression here is a problem:

```
email = email.gsub(/(<+\w)/, "")
```

This removes one or more `<` characters followed by a single word character. What you probably meant was:

```
/<\w+/
```

Though based on your data, you can probably trash everything after the `<`:

```
/<.*/
```

Keep in mind you can chain `gsub` operations together, plus you can rack up a bunch of "cleaner" expressions in an array defined beforehand:

```
MOPS = [
 /<.*/,
 /\A"|"\Z/
]

MOPS.inject(email) do |e, mop|
  e.gsub(mop, '')
end
```